# Issue with servlet defaulting to index servlet. Tomcat 8.0.30 JDK 1.8

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, servlets

So I have a servlet listening on "/ajax/foo", and a servlet listening on "/". When I make a call to /ajax/foo, it initializes that servlet but doesn't call the get or post overridden methods it defaults to "/" for those, even thou I am not extending it, I am extending HttpServlet.

I am also using annotations to setup the servlet paths. I wonder if this can be causing it. I also checked all the methods and even copied over servlet doPost/doGet methods, that are working since I can verify it yet in this servlet still don't get called. Servlet doesn't write anything out, and is being called over ajax (jquery $.post).

Thank you for any help.

```
package ajax;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


@WebServlet("/ajax/foo")
public class FooAjaxServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ThreadAdminActionAjaxServlet() {
        super();
        System.out.println("LOADED");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("GET")
    }
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("POST");
}


}
```

Comment: Post the code snippets

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb added the servlet but it was auto generated by eclipse so I highly doubt that the issue with the actual code.